# How to create statistical reports about data contained in various content types?

Tags: 7, log-messages

I have page in drupal for hockey league. Till now, there was only nodes, some specific content types, simple views, but now, they want to create full statistics for the entire league. I was looking for some modules, but unsuccessfully.

My friends from this league want to type final score of match and system will know who is winner, credit points and calculate any other statistics data for team. I was trying to create something like this with rules, but I failed. I dont know ho to get SUM of fields from one content type, then calculate some value and get it to another content type, filter some values in views and get it to another view for his filtering.

I think that rules, views are insufficient for this. I need help, what way to choose.. trying do this in modelus or best way is to learn module development and create my own module to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Computed field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field). You can use PHP to do calculations from information from other fields and show display the result. If you want, you can also save it to databse for use elsewhere. You can also try to do it in Views with [Views calc](http://drupal.org/project/views_calc). I think Views would be your better bet.

Comment: Views calc is good, but I need to save this values to database because I sort view by this values. For example: I have content type "team" where I have name of team and number of games, and value for games I want to get from another content type "games" where I want to get number of games played byt this team.. something like this: SELECT COUNT(team) where team = 'THIS TEAM'.